# How to deal with column containing multiple comma-separated values in R language

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

There is a column in my data set (CSV file) called `amenities`. It contains values like

```
{ "Wireless Internet", "Wheelchair accessible", Kitchen, Elevator, "Buzzer/wireless intercom", Heating, Washer, Dryer, Essentials, Shampoo, Hangers, "Laptop friendly workspace" }, 
{ TV, "Cable TV", Internet, "Wireless Internet", "Air conditioning", Kitchen, "Smoking allowed", "Pets allowed", "Buzzer/wireless intercom", Heating, "Family/kid friendly", "Smoke detector", "Carbon monoxide, etc.
```

There are around 10k columns like this. I want to convert each amenity
into new column and want to create values as 0 or 1 against each entry.

For example - columns should be created as below:

```
Wireless Internet      WheelChair accesible     Kitchen      Elivator     Buzzer/Wireless
1                      0                        1             1             0
```

Basically, each element of the column create a new column and their values should come like 0 and 1 based on whether the amenity is present in the column or not.

I have input as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDIWh.png)

and I want to get an output like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9HHC.png)

Comment: check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095106/how-can-i-model-the-effect-of-genre-on-movie-ratings/61096200#61096200). You should be able to understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I model the effect of genre on movie ratings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61095106/how-can-i-model-the-effect-of-genre-on-movie-ratings)

Comment: This may help you get started: assuming that your daatframe is called `df`you can do: `amenities_clean <- gsub('[{}"]', '', df$amenities) # remove unwanted stuff
amenities_unique <- unique(unlist(strsplit(amenities_clean, ","))) # get a list of unique amenities
df[amenities_unique] <- NA # set up the columns for each amenity`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann: Thanks for the above split code. It worked. Now my aim is to create new columns in df with these values and if the value is available in the original amenities column then mark as 1 else 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (rather complex) solution (to a rather complex problem):

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:2,
  amenities = c('{"Wireless Internet","Wheelchair accessible",Kitchen,Elevator,"Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,Washer,Dryer,Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Laptop friendly workspace"}',
                 '{TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Smoking allowed","Pets allowed","Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,"Family/kid friendly","Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide}'))
```

Prepare data:

```
amenities_clean <- gsub('[{}"]', '', df$amenities) # remove unwanted stuff 
amenities_split <- strsplit(amenities_clean, ",") # split rows into individual amenities
amenities_unique <- unique(unlist(strsplit(amenities_clean, ","))) # get a list of unique amenities 
df[amenities_unique] <- NA # set up the columns for each amenity
```

Now for the meat of the analysis, using `str_detect` from the package `stringr`:

```
# record presence/absence of individual amenities in each new column:

library(stringr)
for(i in 1:ncol(df[amenities_unique])){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){
    df[amenities_unique][j,i] <- 
      ifelse(str_detect(amenities_split[j], names(df[amenities_unique][i])), 1, 0)
  }
}
```

This will prompt warnings but they seem to be negligible as the result is correct:

```
df
  id
1  1
2  2
                                                                                                                                                                                            amenities
1                               {"Wireless Internet","Wheelchair accessible",Kitchen,Elevator,"Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,Washer,Dryer,Essentials,Shampoo,Hangers,"Laptop friendly workspace"}
2 {TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,"Smoking allowed","Pets allowed","Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,"Family/kid friendly","Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide}
  Wireless Internet Wheelchair accessible Kitchen Elevator Buzzer/wireless intercom Heating Washer Dryer
1                 1                     1       1        1                        1       1      1     1
2                 1                     0       1        0                        1       1      0     0
  Essentials Shampoo Hangers Laptop friendly workspace TV Cable TV Internet Air conditioning Smoking allowed
1          1       1       1                         1  0        0        1                0               0
2          0       0       0                         0  1        1        1                1               1
  Pets allowed Family/kid friendly Smoke detector Carbon monoxide
1            0                   0              0               0
2            1                   1              1               1
```

**EDIT**:

Alternatively, and maybe more economically, instead of the nested `for`loop you can use an `apply` function like this (based on the vectors `amenities_split` and `amenities_unique` from the Preparation phase of the first solution):

```
cbind(df, t(sapply(amenities_split, function(x) 
  table(factor(x, levels = amenities_unique)))))
```